# Trying to send command for object without authority

Tags: c#, unity3d

Buenas, estoy intentando instanciar unos ***GameObjects*** en una partida en LAN en la escena desde unos botones que tengo para que elijas cual quieres instanciar. Desde el ***Host*** todo va perfecto, puedo instanciar los ***GameObjects*** y tanto en el ***Host*** como en el cliente se ve perfectamente sincronizado. El problema es que desde el cliente me da el siguiente error:

> Trying to send command for object without authority.
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour:SendCommandInternal(NetworkWriter,
>   Int32, String)

Aqui os dejo el Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class InstanceUnitats : NetworkBehaviour {

    //Parents Unitats Canvas
    private GameObject parentBytesonian;
    private GameObject parentHominis;

    //Unidades Bytesonians                  //Botones Bytesonians
    public GameObject unitatBasicBS;        public GameObject buttonBasicBS;
    public GameObject unitatHeavyBS;        public GameObject buttonHeavyBS;
    public GameObject unitatVehicleBS;      public GameObject buttonVehicleBS;
    public GameObject unitatMeleeBS;        public GameObject buttonMeleeBS;
    public GameObject unitatGeneralBS;      public GameObject buttonGeneralBS;


    //Unidades Bytesonians                  //Botones Bytesonians
    public GameObject unitatBasicHS;        public GameObject buttonBasicHS;
    public GameObject unitatHeavyHS;        public GameObject buttonHeavyHS;
    public GameObject unitatVehicleOFHS;    public GameObject buttonVehicleOFHS;
    public GameObject unitatVehicleTRHS;    public GameObject buttonVehicleTRHS;
    public GameObject unitatMeleeHS;        public GameObject buttonMeleeHS;
    public GameObject unitatGeneralHS;      public GameObject buttonGeneralHS;

    //Mouse 
    public Vector3 mousePosition;

    void Awake()
    {
        parentBytesonian = gameObject.transform.Find ("BYTESONIANS").gameObject;
        parentHominis = gameObject.transform.Find ("HOMINIS").gameObject;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        //Inicializamos los generales siempre a 1
        StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralBS = 1;
        StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralHS = 1;

        //Si la bool es falsa, puedes escoger las unidades Humanas
        if (StructManager.VG.razaSelected == false) 
        {
            parentHominis.SetActive (true);
        } 
        //Si no, puedes escoger las unidades Bytesonians
        else 
        {
            parentBytesonian.SetActive (true);
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        //---------------BYTESONIANS----------------\\
        //Si las variables se quedan a 0 (es decir, todas las unidades estan instanciadas), borramos los botones
        if( StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaBS == 0 && StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaBS == 0 && 
            StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeBS  == 0 && StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleBS == 0 && 
            StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralBS == 0)
        {
            Destroy (buttonBasicBS);
            Destroy (buttonHeavyBS);
            Destroy (buttonVehicleBS);
            Destroy (buttonMeleeBS);
            Destroy (buttonGeneralBS);
        }

        //--------------HOMINIS SOLARIS--------------\\
        //Si las variables se quedan a 0 (es decir, todas las unidades estan instanciadas), borramos los botones
        if( StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaHS == 0    && StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaHS == 0 && 
            StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeHS  == 0    && StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleOFHS == 0 && 
            StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleTRHS == 0 && StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralHS == 0)
        {
            Destroy (buttonBasicHS);
            Destroy (buttonHeavyHS);
            Destroy (buttonVehicleOFHS);
            Destroy (buttonVehicleTRHS);
            Destroy (buttonMeleeHS);
            Destroy (buttonGeneralHS);
        }
    }

    public void SelectBoton(string accion)
    {
        switch (accion) 
        {
            //Bytesonians
            case "BASICAB": CmdBB ();   break;
            case "HEAVYB":  CmdHB ();   break;
            case "MELEEB":  CmdMB ();   break;
            case "VEHICLEB": CmdVB ();  break;
            case "GENERALB": CmdGB ();  break;

            //Hominis
            case "BASICAHS": CmdBHS (); break;
            case "HEAVYHS": CmdHHS ();  break;
            case "MELEEHS": CmdMHS ();  break;
            case "VEHICLEOFHS": CmdVOFHS ();    break;
            case "VEHICLETRHS": CmdVTRHS ();    break;
            case "GENERALHS": CmdGHS ();    break;
        }
    }

    //-----------------------BYTESONIANS-----------------------\\

    [Command]
    void CmdBB()
    {
        //Si el numero de unidades seleccionadas es mayor o igual a 0...
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaBS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUBasicBS = Instantiate (unitatBasicBS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaBS--;  //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUBasicBS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaBS <= 0)
            {
                buttonBasicBS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUBasicBS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdHB()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaBS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUPesadaBS = Instantiate (unitatHeavyBS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaBS--;  //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUPesadaBS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaBS <= 0)
            {
                buttonHeavyBS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUPesadaBS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdMB()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeBS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUMeleeBS = Instantiate (unitatMeleeBS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeBS--;   //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUMeleeBS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeBS <= 0)
            {
                buttonMeleeBS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUMeleeBS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdVB()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleBS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUVehicleBS = Instantiate (unitatVehicleBS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleBS--; //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUVehicleBS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleBS <= 0)
            {
                buttonVehicleBS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUVehicleBS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdGB()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralBS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUGeneralBS = Instantiate (unitatGeneralBS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralBS--; //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUGeneralBS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralBS <= 0)
            {
                buttonGeneralBS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUGeneralBS);
        }
    }

    //---------------------HOMINIS SOLARIS---------------------\\
    [Command]
    void CmdBHS()
    {
        //Si el numero de unidades seleccionadas es mayor o igual a 0...
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaHS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUBasicHS = Instantiate (unitatBasicHS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaHS--;  //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUBasicHS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadBasicaHS <= 0)
            {
                buttonBasicHS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUBasicHS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdHHS()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaHS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUPesadaHS = Instantiate (unitatHeavyHS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaHS--;  //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUPesadaHS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadPesadaHS <= 0)
            {
                buttonHeavyHS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUPesadaHS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdMHS()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeHS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUMeleeHS = Instantiate (unitatMeleeHS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeHS--;   //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUMeleeHS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadMeleeBS <= 0)
            {
                buttonMeleeHS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUMeleeHS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdVOFHS()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleOFHS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUVehicleOFHS = Instantiate (unitatVehicleOFHS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleOFHS--;   //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUVehicleOFHS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleOFHS <= 0)
            {
                buttonVehicleOFHS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUVehicleOFHS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdVTRHS()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleTRHS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUVehicleTRHS = Instantiate (unitatVehicleTRHS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleTRHS--;   //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUVehicleTRHS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadVehicleTRHS <= 0)
            {
                buttonVehicleTRHS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUVehicleTRHS);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdGHS()
    {
        if (StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralHS > 0) 
        {
            //Instanciamos
            GameObject newUGeneralHS = Instantiate (unitatGeneralHS, mousePosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralHS--; //Restamos 1 a las unidades seleccionadas
            RayCastRatoli.instance.unitat = newUGeneralHS;

            if(StructManager.VG.unidadGeneralHS <= 0)
            {
                buttonGeneralHS.GetComponent<Button> ().interactable = false;
            }

            NetworkServer.Spawn(newUGeneralHS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usted tiene componentes deshabilitados, antes de instanciarlos? si es asi, intente un simple test de hacer lo contrario teniendolo habilitado primero.Saludos